# Gravitational Potential Energy in a collision of an asteroid and a planet in the solar system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, astrophysics, potential-energy, collision

Suppose that an asteroid collide with a planet in our solar system.

Since the solar system is a system with more than two bodies so I’m not sure how it affects Gravitational Potential Energy of the whole system due to their new position in space after the collision.
Also, heat is produced from the collision so I wonder what happens to Gravatational Potential Energy of the system.

The main question is, Is the total energy conserved in these collisions?

Comment: 1) Conservation does not mean constancy. Conservation requires you to consider the energy flow across the boundary of your defined system. 2) Calculating GPE changes of a multi-body system requires one to consider *every* pair of gravitationally interacting bodies and their positional changes.

Comment: @BillN  I’m sorry if my question is too basic.  Suppose KE doesn’t change after the collision of an asteroid and a planet in the solar system. Does total  GPE of this multi-body system decrease?  If so, is the decrease in GPE of the system equal to heat produced in the collision?

Comment: Those are totally different questions than the original. If positions of massive objects change relative to one another, the GPE changes. Has nothing to do with internal energy of the objects. If objects collide non-elastically, the internal energy of the objects will change.

Comment: @BillN  If positions of objects change relative to one another, internal energy of the system remains the same because the change in GPE is converted to KE. Have I got it right? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, basically, without collisions $\Delta PE=-\Delta KE$. If collisions occur, then KE is lost to internal energies (temperature changes, material structural changes, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Total Energy of solar system is not conserved anyway as a lot of sun's energy escapes the system in the form of radiation every second.

So, small amount of collision energy will escape in the form of radiation. Rest will be conserved assuming no matter escapes solar system as a result of collision. This also assumes that the pre collision energy of the asteroid belongs to solar system and it did not come from outside.

Potential energy decreases by the same amount that the kinetic energy of the asteroid increases. This requires you to define initial time from which you want to calculate change in kinetic energy.

Comment: @parker: The answer does not change. Only thing that escapes the system is either radiation, or if any debree happen to escape. In extreme collisions, gravitational waves would escape. That is it. Other than that PE+KE remains same depending upon how you consider. Obviously the asteroid stops post collision, but the KE is transferred to planet parts in some form or other. If it does not escape the system, it is part of system. I have listed the escaping parts.